# Merge today's date with a timespan data type value

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, timespan

I'm trying to merge today's date with an existing time value I have stored in a sql server database. Let me give you an example:

ClientTradedTime = "16:52:01" (this is of type timespan)

I want to merge that value with today's date in variable of type DateTime to use it else where, example:

DateTime mydate;

mydate = "2014-02-04 16:52:01" (this is what I want to see when I store it in my database)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [Datime.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `TimeSpan` to the `DateTime`'s Date property and you will get your desired `DateTime` like:

```
DateTime updatedDt = mydate.Date.Add(ClientTradedTime);
```

Consider the following example:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ClientTradedTime = new TimeSpan(16, 52, 51);
DateTime updatedDt = myDate.Date.Add(ClientTradedTime);
```

This will give you:

```
updatedDt = {04/02/2014 4:52:51 PM}
```

`myDate.Date` would give you `DateTime` with Time set to `00:00:00` and then you can add your `TimeSpan` to it.